# How to change the android sharedPreferences save path?

Tags: android

I want to change the android sharedPreferences  save path,the sharedPreferences save in /data/data/xxx.xxx.xxx/shared_prefs,i want to change path to /sdcard. how i do?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify where shared preferences are stored. Since shared preferences are simply stored in an XML file, you are welcome to read and write XML data on external storage as you see fit.

BTW, never use `/sdcard`. Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. `/sdcard` is not the correct path for over a third of existing Android devices.